# In Joomla 1.6, how can I disable entering my site other than menu links

Tags: joomla, components, hyperlink

I activated SEO links in Joomla Config. But same page is accessible with more links.

For example,

Menu Link      :
www.mysite.com/tr/iwant/tobelikethat.html

Component Link :

www.mysite.com/tr/component/content/article.html?id=23

Not Seo Link   :

www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23%3blobblob&catid=8&Itemid=124&lang=tr

I want to disable entering other than menu link.
Can you help me ?

Comment: disabling this, you will stop many components from working as some are built to work only with not-seo links. In fact all Joomla Administration is "not-seo". Not recommending

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the answer you want, it is the one you need and ultimately the "correct" answer.

The only possible way of making Joomla work in that way would be a serious layer of system plugins or core hacks to the jroute. Doing it this way is a BAD idea. Do not do it.